# How can I grep IP block with awk?

Tags: bash, awk

I have a text file like this:

```
1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9|192.168.1.1
1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9|192.168.2.1
1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9|192.168.22.1
1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9|192.168.222.1
```

I need to print if $10 starts with "192.168.2.", like this:

```
1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9|192.168.2.1
```

I tried like this (I use var because I get this ip block from other file, this is just sample):

```
awk -v var="192.168.2." -F'|' '{if ($10 ~ "^" var) print $0;}'
```

output:

```
1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9|192.168.2.1
1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9|192.168.22.1
1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9|192.168.222.1
```

How can I fix that? Why does not work last `.` in var?

Comment: Try print $10 in if block.

Comment: You could also use `grep` if you regex the fields, e.g. `IP="192.168.2." && IP=$(sed 's/\./\\./g' <<< "${IP}") && grep -E "^([^|]*[|]){9}${IP}" input.txt`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this `awk`:

```
awk -v var="192[.]168[.]2[.]" -F'|' '$10 ~ var{print}' file
```

If you can't change the input `IP` format, try the below.

```
awk -v var="192.168.2." -F'|' 'BEGIN{gsub("[.]", "\\.", var)} $10 ~ var{print}'
```

Output:

```
1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9|192.168.2.1
```

Comment: Right but you don't need the `{print}` as that's the default behavior when the preceding condition is true. All you need is `awk ... '$10 ~ var' file`. UNLESS the IP address doesn't always start with 3 digits and then you need `awk ... '$10 ~ "^"var' file` to anchor it.

Answer (score 1):

The `.` character is a wildcard. You should replace instances in your match-string with `\.` and you should surround regular expressions with `/`. If you want to parameterise the IP address it might be neater for you to do this

```
var="192\.168\.2\."
awk -F'|' '{if ($10 ~ /^'${var}'/) print $0;}'
```

You might also like to use Awk's pattern-rule semantics:

```
awk -F'|' '$10 ~ /^'${var}'/ {print $0}'
```

Which is a little neater.

You can escape your IP address like so:

```
var=$(echo ${var} | sed 's/\./\\./g')
```

Comment: sorry regular expressions should be enclosed in `/` rather than `"`

Comment: What I am trying to tell is `\.` is not giving expected output. Since, `awk` is treated as plain `.`.

Comment: The second form I provided works ... not sure how to get it tow work with the `ìf` version ...

Answer (score 1):

```
gawk -F"|" 'match($10, "192.168.2.*") {print}' input-file
```

I get the following output:

```
1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9|192.168.2.1
1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9|192.168.22.1
1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9|192.168.222.1
```

I guess it's the easiest way to achieve that.

Comment: OP said that IP may change dynamically.